# nested fields with has_many through relationship - duplicate incomplete records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, cocoon-gem

I have the current model relationship:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :subjects, through: :group_memberships
  has_many :entries, through: :group_memberships
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :group_memberships, allow_destroy: true

class GroupMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :subject
  belongs_to :entry

class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_memberships, through: :entries, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :group_memberships, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :group_memberships, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :groups, allow_destroy: true
```

With cocoon nested fields and simpleform - when I add or update existing objects - two incomplete group_membership records are created (i.e they are splitting the required foreign-keys over two models.

The only difference between this and the associations I normally use is the join table in this case has three foreign keys rather than two.

The SQL queries:

```
INSERT INTO `groups` (`name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('test group', '2016-01-11 15:53:22', '2016-01-11 15:53:22')
INSERT INTO `group_memberships` (`subject_id`, `group_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (16, 18, '2016-01-11 15:53:22', '2016-01-11 15:53:22')
INSERT INTO `group_memberships` (`entry_id`, `group_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (20, 18, '2016-01-11 15:53:22', '2016-01-11 15:53:22')
```

The parameters in the controller seem to be normal:

```
"groups_attributes"=>{"1452527593321"=>{"name"=>"test group", "subject_ids"=>["", "16"], "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"20"}
```

I really am a bit lost as to why I am dealing with duplicated incomplete queries when the parameters appear fine

The form itself looks like below:

```
<div id="groups">
  <div id="groups_from_list">
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :groups do |group| %>
        <%= render 'group_fields', :f => group %>
      <% end %>
  </div>
  <%= link_to_add_association 'add a group', f, :groups, :class => 'btn btn-primary btn' %>
</div>
```

I have not had any problems with standard has_many through associations using nested forms - but I assume having the three foreign keys in the group_membership join table is causing the problem.

```
**Group Fields Partial**

<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.input :name , input_html: { class: 'form-control-small' }, label: "Group name" %>
  <%= f.association :subjects,
                      include_blank: false,
                      label_method: :full_name,
                      label: "Attendees",
                      collection: Subject.order(:last_name),
                      input_html: { class: 'select2-issue-X' },
                      placeholder: "add attendees" %>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove", f, :class => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs'%>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the `group_fields` partial? I do not see an `entry_id` in the parameters posted to the controller, so it is not clear to me how the one group posted (with two `subject_ids`) could lead to the two inserts for `group_memberships` you show.

Comment: I updated the original post with the partial.  I am indeed confused because there is no `entry_id` in the parameters - but somehow one of the two incomplete `group_memberships` records has a correct `entry_id`.  If i manually merge the two records together - everything seems to work fine

Comment: There is no `entry_id` in the view? How do you set it?

Comment: Originally I added a hidden field to supply the entry_id - but doing so will produce the following error `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'entry_id' for Group.)`.  What also confuses me more is that Activerecord is able to infer the correct entry_id for one of the record creations without any hidden fields (as shown in the third SQL query in my original post.

Comment: Mmmmmm how does your controller code look? I think you should consider to create `group_memberships` instead of directly trying to add `subjects` to groups. Or your controller code will try to set the `entry_id`. From the code you show now there is no way rails will set the `entry_id` automatically.

Comment: The controller code is just the REST standard - no extra stuff there.  I was actually thinking the same thing and just using group_memberships as the nested field - but going down that route could add a lot of view clutter.  I had an older implementation that used the same models but instead the `group_membership` model used a belongs to relationship to group and subject, while I added a group_id key to the entry model directly - it seemed to work better except for some reason I am unable to remove the groups in the nested fields.

Comment: With regards to the removing: make sure you allow the `:id` and `:_destroy` fields in the strong parameters. No extra stuff in the controller? And in the model then?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by going using a different model relationship - the one I had used in my original post seems to be unsupported by the standard nested fields implementations - although it may have been solvable with overriding controller and model code.

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :subjects, through: :group_memberships

class GroupMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :subject

class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups, through: :entries
  has_many :group_memberships, through: :groups, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :groups, allow_destroy: true
```